# System Linq Enumerable error while using intersect

Tags: c#, list, linq, text

I have 3 lists and I'm trying to display their common items in a text box, and while I am implementing the method

```
var result = l1.Intersect(l2);                
textBox1.Text = "";
textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
```

while l1 is my first list and l2 is my second list
I get the error:

> System.Linq.Enumerable+d__70`1[System.String]

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I dont believe thats an error. Its the value assigned to your variable because thats what .ToString on a list does.. If you need values, you need to do a string.Join() on them.

Comment: Your `result` is an enumeration. It's essentially another list. You can't simply display contents of the list by converting the list to a string.

Comment: That is not an error, it's the string representation of the intersect linq query. You will need to first decide what you want in that string and then write code that produces it. On a lark, try `textBox1.Text = string.Join(", ", result);`

Comment: @Jawad thanks a lot your comment helped me.

Comment: @Sach thanks for your help

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen a million thanks, solved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `result` is an `IEnumerable`, and that interface does not override `ToString()`, you're seeing the default implementation of [`Object.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.8), which is to return the fully qualified name of the type of the object.

To resolve this, you can decide how you want to display the items and write them out yourself, for example the following displays the items separated by a comma:

```
textBox1.Text = string.Join(", ", result);
```